# dplyr - summarise with condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tribble(
  ~Date, ~A1, ~A2,~B1,~B2,
  as.Date("2019-01-01"), 20, 10,20, 10,
  as.Date("2019-01-01"), 20 ,5,20,5,
  as.Date("2019-01-01"), 10, 2,10,20,
  as.Date("2019-01-01"), 20, 60,0,0,
  as.Date("2019-01-01"), 30, 4,20,5,
  as.Date("2019-02-01"), 0, 0,16,8,
  as.Date("2019-02-01"), 0, 0,0,40,
  as.Date("2019-02-01"), 0, 0,4,2,
  as.Date("2019-02-01"), 4, 8,10,6,
  as.Date("2019-02-01"), 6, 3,0,0,
  as.Date("2019-03-01"), 20, 8,23,9,
  as.Date("2019-03-01"), 60, 4,0,0,
  as.Date("2019-03-01"), 4, 2,8,3,
  as.Date("2019-03-01"), 0, 6,10,0
)
```

For each day I want to calculate the mean of (A1-B1) and of (A2-B2).
For A1-B1 I want to use only rows where A1>B1 and A1>0,B1>0.
For A2-B2 I want to use only rows where A2>B2 and A2>0,B2>0.

This is what I have tried:

```
data_mean = data %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(
      mean_1 = mean(A1[A1>=B1 & A1>0 & B1>0] - B1[A1>=B1 & A1>0 & B1>0]),
      mean_2 = mean(A2[A2>=B2 & A2>0 & B2>0] - B2[A2>=B2 & A2>0 & B2>0]))
```

Is there a way to use the filter function while using summarise function? Or a smarter way to apply my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**
Thank to akrun!!! Now it works!

```
data %>%  
  filter(if_all(where(is.numeric),  ~ . > 0)) %>% 
  mutate(i1 = A1 >= B1, i2 = A2 >= B2) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(mean1 = mean(A1[i1] - B1[i1]), mean2 = mean(A2[i2] - B2[i2]))
```

Output:

```
  Date       mean1 mean2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-01   2.5     0
2 2019-02-01 NaN       2
3 2019-03-01 NaN     NaN
```

**First version**
I get almost akrun's solution. But can't handle the minus numbers

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  filter_if(is.numeric, all_vars((.) != 0)) %>% 
  filter(A1>=B1 | A2>=B2) %>% 
  summarise(mean1 = mean(A1-B1),
            mean2 = mean(A2-B2))
```

Output:

```
  Date       mean1 mean2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-01   2.5 -4.75
2 2019-02-01  -6    2
```

Comment: Here also the issue is with `|` in second filter.  It could increase the number of elements because it is checking whether either one of them is true, while the OP wanted A1 - B1 to only use `A1>= B1` and likewise for A2-B2

Comment: I just recognized your comment for Anoushiravan R. Thank you akrun.

Comment: You could change it to `data %>%  filter(if_all(is.numeric,  ~ . > 0)) %>% mutate(i1 = A1 >= B1, i2 = A2 >= B2) %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(mean1 = mean(A1[i1] - B1[i1]), mean2 = mean(A2[i2] - B2[i2]))` the `if_all` is from the latest version

Answer (score 5):

If we don't want to repeat the expressions, create a temporary column.  Also, this can be done for multiple columns within `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(A1, A2), ~ {
       tmp <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'A', 'B'))
       i1 <- . >= tmp & . > 0 & tmp >0
       mean(.[i1] - tmp[i1])})) %>%
   rename_with(~ str_replace(., 'A', 'mean_'), -Date)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Date       mean_1 mean_2
#* <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2019-01-01    2.5      0
#2 2019-02-01  NaN        2
#3 2019-03-01  NaN      NaN
```

---

Or another option is to convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, do the `filter/group_by/summarise` and then reshape to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = A1:B2, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), 
       names_sep = '(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d)') %>% 
   filter(A >= B, A > 0, B > 0) %>% 
   group_by(Date, grp = str_c('mean_', grp)) %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(A - B), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = mean) %>%
   complete(Date = unique(data$Date))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Date       mean_1 mean_2
#  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2019-01-01    2.5      0
#2 2019-02-01   NA        2
#3 2019-03-01   NA       NA
```

Comment: The across function doesn't work for me not matter what I try

Comment: @john22 can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  I used `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.4’`

Comment: Thank you dear @akrun for your hint.  I guess in case that either of these statements is TRUE or Both are TRUE, we can have the required rows. I checked it once again there seems to be no problem but if there is anything you think may improve my code I would be grateful to know.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I think the filtering should be separate as in the updated post with `pivot_longer`

Comment: @akrun You suggest I put a comma in place of `|`? In that way I think there is no output.
I thought when we use comma it works as `&`.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR that wouldn't work because what happens is that if you do & or |, it still uses for both cases and the outcome would be either few rows or more rows than expected.  If you are using `map`, then probably either this `data %>% select(-Date) %>% split.default(str_remove(names(.), '\\D+')) %>% map_dfr(~ .x %>% bind_cols(., Date = data$Date) %>% filter(.[[1]] >= .[[2]] & if_all(-Date, ~ . > 0)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(mean = mean(cur_data()[[1]] - cur_data()[[2]])) ) %>% complete(Date = unique(data$Date))`

Comment: @AnoushiravanR the `,` in `filter` is for `&` expression and it may reduce the number of rows

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much indeed. I'm just trying to understand this code, it looks great. I'm so sorry to follow your comment cause there main reason I'm visiting this site is to learn more from highly skilled people like you and not at all proving my points.

Comment: @akrun I never thought `|` would increase the elements. I guess I have to pay attention to that. Great point thank you.

Comment: Dear @akrun Would you please explain the last 3 lines of your `pivot_longer` code in particular the part you use `complete` , since I didn't realize how I could find out to use `complete` in the end. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR The reason is that in the `filter` step one of the dates got removed.  With `complete`, the original unique dates from the data is restored with that date showing NA for both mean

Comment: Thank you very much dear @akrun for your explanation. It seems to be such a useful function.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code gets you to your desired output:

```
library(dplyr)


data %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(A1 >= B1 & B1 > 0 | A2 >= B2 & B2 > 0) %>%
  mutate(sub1 = A1 - B1, 
         sub2 = A2 - B2) %>% 
  summarise(mean1 = mean(sub1), 
            mean2 = mean(sub2))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Date       mean1 mean2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-01   2.5 -4.75
2 2019-02-01  -6    2
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the desired output.

Comment: I got the filtering parts wrong so I made some slight modifications and think this is the output you are looking for.